# Convert buffer of ASCII Decimals to a string or array of chars in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, parsing, buffer

I'm trying to open and read a CSV file that holds data that is needed to set capabilities. I need to set the capabilities based off what capabilities are read in from the CSV file. I open the file and read the data into a buffer. That's where I am stuck. I now want to use that data in the buffer to make string or character comparison to enter if else statements. For example my csv file looks like this:

1000, CAP_SETPCAP, CAP_NET_RAW, CAP_SYS_ADMIN

The first number is the euid and the rest are the capabilities that I want to set for a process. When I read it into a buffer the buffer holds ASCII decimals. I want to be able to convert the buffer into a string or array so I can make comparisons.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

         FILE *fp;
         fp = fopen("csvtest.csv", "r");
         char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];
         char *newCaps[] = {};

         if(!fp){
             printf("did not open\n");
         }

         fgets(buff, 1024, fp);

         int i = 0;
         //I don't know how to just get the size of what was put into the buffer
         while(i < size_of_buffer){
              //these are the comparisons I'd like to make, I know this isn't right
              if(buffer[1000] == "1000"){
                    printf("This is the correct euid\n");
                    newCaps[0] = buffer[CAP_SETPCAP];
                    newCaps[1] = buffer[CAP_NET_RAW];
                    newCaps[2] = buffer[CAP_SYS_ADMIN];
              }
           i++;
         }
```

Something along these lines.

Comment: to compare strings use `strcmp()` (or, to compare parts of strings, `strncmp()`)

Comment: Will strcmp() work with comparing a buffer of integers?

Comment: `if (strncmp(buffer, "1000,", 5) == 0) { /* ok */ }` compares `buffer[0]` with `'1'`, `buffer[1]` with `'0'`, ..., `buffer[4]` with `','` and goes into `/* ok */` if all match.

Comment: How would I get it to skip to the start of the string after the comma though to make the comparison of buffer[CAP_XXX_XXX] == "CAP_XXX_XXXX"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the `strtok()` [function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok_r.3.html). It separates a string in different tokens according to a delimiter you set to it, and returns a pointer to that string, which you may want to compare to the other string.

It is a good tool for you to separate and handle standarized delimited information.

Comment: so I ended up doing strtok() and splitting the string on the " , " so now it's broken up. But how would I do comparisons now?

Comment: Ok, so now you use this function `strcmp()`. Here's your manual: https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp

Comment: Look at this implementation for comparing a string with other "PATH". 

```for (i = 0; environ[i] != NULL; i++)
 {
 if (strcomparer(environ[i], "PATH") == 0)```